# SharePoint list form - Column conditional formatting in Swedish

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, list-form

I'm using SP in Swedish at work and want to add conditional formatting for show/hide columns on a list form.

I want pretty much exactly this but translated into Swedish syntax:

```
=if([$Category] == 'Product Management', 'true', 'false')
```

I've tried to iterate variations without any luck...

```
=OM([$Category] == "Product Management"; "sant"; "falskt")
```

Anyone with clue?

Comment: Did you try using formula in English language? Make sure to use the correct **[internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)** of your SharePoint list columns in the formula. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Try `=[$Category]=='Product Management'`, shouldn't be a variation in expression syntax for locale. Though that is true for calculated columns.